# WebStorm file watchers on Windows

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, livescript

I want a file watcher for LiveScript, so I installed it with `npm install LiveScript -g` and this works like expected. I can now type `livescript` into `cmd` and compile files.

But when I try to use `livescript` as `Program` in a watcher, WebStorm tells me *Cannot run program "livescript"...*

The command seems to be globally accessible, but somehow not for WebStorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide a full path to livescript.cmd (should be something like 'C:\Users\your.name\AppData\Roaming\npm\livescript.cmd') in a Program field - this should help